# New to javascript, radio buttons don't work, not allowed to use parameters

Tags: javascript, button, radio-button

I'm trying to make radiobuttons with a javascript function that gets called when a button is selected to make an image appear depending on what they click. However, after looking it up for a while I have nothing since some tell me to do document.formName.name.value; some tell me to use an id with my buttons and just use a `document.getElementByID("");` etc.

This is for a project and we havent used parameters yet and I dont know how to implement them in the HTML as well

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        img{height:200px;}
        body{background-image:url('wood.jpg');}
        span.a1{margin-left:150px; display:inline-block;}
        h2, span, h4, div{font-family:helvetica; color:white;}
        h2 {text-align:center; margin-top:150px;}
        img.display{position:absolute; left:400px; height:300px; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        dex1=0;
        stam1=0;
        str1=0;
        intel1=0;
        agil1=0;
        function counter()
        {
            document.getElementById("dex").innerHTML = dex1;
            document.getElementById("stam").innerHTML = stam1;
            document.getElementById("str").innerHTML = str1;
            document.getElementById("intel").innerHTML = intel1;
            document.getElementById("agil").innerHTML = agil1;
        }
        function classChoice()
        {
            if(document.getElementById('mage').checked)
                {
                    classtype = "<img class='display' src='mage.jpg'>";
                    document.getElementById("mage").innerHTML=classtype;
                }
            else if(document.getElementById('paladin').checked)
                {
                    classtype = "<img class='display' src='paladin.jpg'>";
                    document.getElementById("Paladin").innerHTML=classtype;
                }
            else if(document.getElementById('hunter').checked)
                {
                    classtype = "<img class='display' src='hunter.jpg'>";
                    document.getElementById("hunter").innerHTML=classtype;
                }
            else if(document.getElementById('rogue').checked)
                {
                    classtype = "<img class='display' src='rogue.jpg'>";
                    document.getElementById("rogue").innerHTML=classtype;
                }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2> Awesome MMO </h2>
    <span class="a1">
        <h4> Dexterity </h4>
        <span onmousedown="dex1++; counter();">
            +
        </span>
        <span id="dex">
        0
        </span>
        <span onmousedown="dex1--; counter();">
            -
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="a1">
        <h4> Stamina </h4>
        <span onmousedown="stam1++; counter();">
            +
        </span>
        <span id="stam">
        0
        </span>
        <span onmousedown="stam1--; counter();">
            -
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="a1">
        <h4> Strength </h4>
        <span onmousedown="str1++; counter();">
            +
        </span>
        <span id="str">
        0
        </span>
        <span onmousedown="str1--; counter();">
            -
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="a1">
        <h4> Intellect </h4>
        <span onmousedown="intel1++; counter();">
            +
        </span>
        <span id="intel">
        0
        </span> 
        <span onmousedown="intel1--; counter();">
            -
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="a1">
        <h4> Agility </h4>
        <span onmousedown="agil1++; counter();">
            +
        </span>
        <span id="agil">
        0
        </span>
        <span onmousedown="agil1--; counter();">
            -
        </span>
    </span>
            <h2> Class </h2>
            <span class="a1">
            <br />
            <form name="class">
                    <input type="radio" name = "classes" id="mage" onmousedown="classChoice();"> <img src = "mage.jpg" />
                    <input type="radio" name = "classes" id = "Paladin" onmousedown="classChoice();"> <img src = "Paladin.png" />
                    <input type="radio" name = "classes" id = "hunter" onmousedown="classChoice();"> <img src = "hunter.PNG" />
                    <input type="radio" name = "classes" id = "rogue" onmousedown="classChoice();"> <img src = "rogue.jpg" />           
            </form>
            </span>
    <span id="picture">
    </span>
</body>
```

Comment: Don't use `==` true, it's almost always superfluous.

Comment: not sure how to use jfiddle since I have images that are hard to direct path

Comment: @minitech In Javascript, you might want to check if an object is actually a boolean `true`, and not a different "truthy" value. (Of course you'd need threequals for that: `if (something === true)`.)

Comment: @Inerdial: Exactly. `== true` is almost always superfluous.

Comment: Although sometimes you might want to check if a variable is actually the boolean true and not just "truthy", most times that you see code with `something==true` or `something===true` the type of "something" is not in question, like `element.checked===true`. I used to work with a guy who always wrote `element.checked==false` even though everybody else on the team would say `!element.checked`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the `onmousedown` makes it so I would have to double click each radio button as I had unintentionally found out angrily clicking on my button.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might want to check out jQuery for this - it could definitely make things easier for you.

[Link to jQuery Home](http://jquery.com)

Using this library you could simplify your code - here's a semi-complete example based on your requirements -it only looks at the click event on the radio button - you'll need to add a check to see whether or not the element is already checked:

```
$('input').click(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('id') == 'mage') {
    //add code here to set the source of your image
    $(myImage).attr('src','path/to/your/chosen/image');
});
```

You can repeat with else if statements to handle each of your cases or write a more elegant solution.  Learning a library like jQuery (or others such as prototype or extjs) will GREATLY reduce the amount of time you spend writing javascript and will improve the cross browser compatibility of your work

Answer (score 1):

Getting your radio buttons by id should be fine, but use the `checked` property to test whether they're currently checked:

```
if(document.getElementById('mage').checked)
{
     classtype = "<img class='display' src='mage.jpg'>";
     document.getElementById("picture").innerHTML=classtype;         
}
```

Of course your html does not show an element with an id of "picture" -- did you just not show that?

You'll also want to change the name on your form -- having it have the same name as your radio buttons could cause problems.  Assuming you were to change it to "frm", you could access a collection of all your radio buttons like this:

```
var allRadios = document.getElementsByName("classes");
```

Comment: For the picture thing it was placeholder code that I changed for a few minutes to show someone what I was trying to do and I forgot to change it back before posting. Sorry about that. I tried the checked property, however it's still not returning anything.

Comment: `document.getElementById('mage').checked` did not work for you?  Or did you try something else?

Comment: 'document.getElementById('mage').checked' didn't work. I opened the chrome debugger and I get the error of "cannot read checked of null"

Comment: the only way that wouldn't work was if there wasn't an element with an id of mage on your form.  Can you triple check that nothing is mistyped?  Can you try it with paladin?

Comment: I tried it with all four buttons, they dont seem to be responding and I still get that error. Triple checked and caught a capitalization error with Paladin but the others are fine

Comment: @Arcane - post your entire html and javascript

Comment: @Arcane - you've got me stumped.  I would say strip the code to a bare minimum, just the radio buttons, and see if that works.  Then slowly add in the rest of your html and see when it breaks.  Also, then the web page first loads, check the chrome console to see if there are any errors.  Sorry I can't be of more help

Answer (score 0):

You should use `change()` function of jQuery , if you want to do something whenever the selection changes.

```
$('#myRadioButton').change(function(){

    // Do whatever you want to do with the new value 
    // You get the value with $(this).val()

});
```